# Retina MBP 2015 does not recognise third external monitor

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I am trying to get this system to run:

- Laptop lid closed.
- 1 Monitor connected with DVI-miniDP adapter to a thunderbolt port
- 1 Monitor connected with DVI-miniDP adapter to a thunderbolt port
- 1 Monitor connected with a DVI to HDMI port on the HDMI port.

I can only get the notebook to recognise 2 of these displays. I can get the third display to work, only if I disconnect an existing one.

Interestingly, if I replace one of the DVI-miniDP displays with a VGA-miniDP adapter on one of the TB ports, then all 3 displays work. Yet I don't want to keep a displayed with VGA (for obviously limitations), so I was wondering if some can provide some pointers on how to make this setup work correctly.

Running 10.10.4

Comment: Is the VGA resolution the same as the native one?

Answer (score 1):

It depends which MacBook you have. The cheaper ones only have integrated graphics processor (Intel Iris Graphics 6100) which runs from your CPU. The expensive ones have a separate graphics card (AMD Radeon R9 M370X) with 2Gb memory which supports more display or higher resolution displays.

**Macbook with integrated Intel graphics:**

Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on **up to two external displays**, both at millions of colors.

**Macbook with AMD graphics card:**

Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on **up to two external displays**, both at millions of colors.

Source: [Apple MacBook Pro Retina specs](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs-retina/) - Graphics and Video support

Comment: Given the information above, it is clear that the MacBook Pro can only support two external displays, despite the availability of three ports with display capability.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The model in question has a discreet AMD GPU. The assertion of only 2 external displays is not correct, as right now I am running the system with 4 displays (the three mentioned in the question + the laptop screen). Yet, one of them is connected using a VGA-to-miniDP adapter on the TB port. Switching that to DVI-to-miniDP causes the display to not be recognised.

Comment: Isnt that adapter faulty maybe?

Comment: Nope, I have tested the adapter with the other display that has a DVI cable, it works.